# Cannot run SQLiteStudio 3.2.1 on Mac OS Catalina? Stuck at choose language

Tags: macos-catalina, sqlitestudio

I am a beginner. I've searched online for others with a similar issue but didn't get results. I am trying to learn SQL and the course I'm following is using **SQLiteStudio**.

I have downloaded the *.dmg file and installed but upon running the app, it asks to choose a language. I choose English(US) and say OK. it prompts again for language. over and over again. No matter what language I choose it will not progress.

I have deleted the app files and reinstalled, same issue.

https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/releases/tag/3.2.1 is the download link and i am downloading `InstallSQLiteStudio-3.2.1.dmg (installer)`  file.

I am on **Mac OS Catalina, 10.15.1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pawel we realized this was a permissions issue on Mac.

I reset the permissions on my home folder and this solved the issue.

I followed the steps in the `reset permissions` section of this link: [apple support - reset home permissions](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203538)

Posting the answer in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was not working, clicking on the lock  in *Privacy & Security* then allow application to be installed from *Anywhere*. It was still showing a window giving two choices Move to Trash or Cancel, because the software was judged suspicious.

So I used `brew` and it worked fine:

```sh
brew install --cask sqlitestudio
```